# USB connected device; permission change

Tags: 16.04, permissions

I  have my RCA Tablet connected to my pc through the USB port. My computer is running Ubuntu 16. Can I change the permission to my tablet through the terminal? (Please write the code out step by step)

Answer (score 0):

No.

I have the RCA Viking Pro, and the USB connection treats the RCA tablet just like an external flash memory.

There is no control capability.

Comment: Sorry - no code to write out.  If you somehow rooted the RCA and caused the USB port to become a tty interface then you would just use a terminal emulator on the PC (like PuTTY) to log in and have a full terminal session.

Comment: thank you very much for your input! Would you have any hint on how to root the RCA tablet? I already asked stackexchange and no has a clue how to do it. They say use TWRP and I can't use that unless my tablet is rooted first.